# How to resolve Python import module?

Tags: python

I'm on Ubuntu 20.4. When I execute a Python script, I get the following error and sys.path.
[image]

I installed the packages with pip3 and they are located in

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
```

When I look at the installed packages for python3 and python3.8 interpreter, I see "binance" package installed and recognized.
[image: recognized packages]

I tried to set PYTHONPATH to point to my project folder, but that didn't help either.

```
echo $PYTHONPATH --> /algos_python
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed `binance` from PYPI but you are not using it. You are using `python-binance` and you need to install it. (Using `python3 -m pip install python-binance`) and then run your code again. See [this](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance#quick-start) for more info on this.

Comment: thanks man. that was exactly it. I generated the requirements.txt file automatically and somehow it took the binance dependency. Thanks again, you saved me a couple hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. `python3 -m pip install python-binance`
2. If you are calling your file `binance.py` (Or have a file/folder named that in your directory), and then trying to import from `binance.client`, python will look in your `binance.py` file instead of the library. So try renaming your local file.